# Coset Leaders and Syndromes

Tags: matrices, coding-theory, parity

This is my Parity check matrix For Coset Leader `100010` Syndrome is `101` Could any one help me with the procedure, since I figured out that adding up both the columns isn't much of help.

```
1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Not clear (and the lack of punctuation does not help). What is the question?

Comment: Its a parity check matrix H, where as I need to find a syndrome for coset leader 100010 and Its syndrome is 101, but I dont know the method to get it

Comment: I think the coset leader should have $7$ components--to match the number of columns of the parity check matrix--(rather than the $6$ components given in the problem).

Comment: I just need the method to find the Syndrome for the coset leader 100010

Comment: I edited the Matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syndrome of a vector $\vec{v}$ is given by $\vec{v}H^T$.  In your case this amounts to the transpose of the sum of the first and fifth columns of $H$ (presumably over $\mathbb{Z}_2$)

---

Syndrome of $\vec{v}$ is given by

$$\text{syn}(\vec{v})=\vec{v}H^T=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0&1&0  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\ 1&1&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Actually i am new to this, could you show a step by step procedure.